# Sencha touch make the viewport masked in slidenavigation

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my sencha Touch application i am using the slidenavigation, when ever i click on the hamburger icon the menu slides out.

Now i want to mask the active  view when menu slide is open. 
My code for slidenavigation is as below

```
createMenu: function(){

        var items = [
            {
                xtype:'button',
                text:'Home',
                ui: 'mainmenu',


                    listeners: {
            tap: function(){

                 if(Ext.Viewport.getMenus().left.isHidden()){
                                 Ext.Viewport.showMenu('left');

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Ext.Viewport.hideMenu('left');
                                 Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype: 'main'});
                            }
            }
        }
            },
            {
                xtype:'button',
                text:'Videos',
                ui: 'mainmenu',
                listeners: {
            tap: function(){
                 Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype: 'videolist'});
                 if(Ext.Viewport.getMenus().left.isHidden()){
                                Ext.Viewport.showMenu('left');

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Ext.Viewport.hideMenu('left');

                            }
              }
             }
            }
        ];

        return Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {


            width: 200,
            scrollable: 'vertical',
            items: items,
            id: 'mainmenu',
            cls: 'mainmenu',
        });
    }
```

Comment: If I understand you correct you want to display a mask over the parent view of your slidenavigation / current view display?

Answer (score 0):

**To show your mask,** before "*Ext.Viewport.showMenu()*"
    add this line :

```
Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().setMasked(true);
```

**To hide your mask,** after  "*Ext.Viewport.hideMenu()*"
    add this line :

```
Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().setMasked(false);
```